# Is it a good practice to use static initializers?

Tags: java, static-initialization, static-initializer

Is there any alternative to static initializers in Java?

Just a random example:

```
private static List<String> list;

static {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("foo")
}
```

Doesn't it make debugging harder?

Comment: Especially if that code throws an exception. There is no one size answer here

Comment: Kinda depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  If you can create an instance of the class, you can usually get away with doing this in a constructor.  If you're using dependency injection/inversion of control, you'd rely on your DI layer to inject a list for your class with a specified value for you.  **You need to add more details** to this question so we can understand the context you're in.

Comment: You can also make a private static method that does the initialization (and can trap an Exception and report it). So `static List<String> list = initList();` and then `private static List<String> initList() { ... }`. Such an approach allows for setting a break point and/or logging in the private static method.

Comment: Why would debugging be harder? --- *"Is there any alternative?"* Singleton.

Comment: @KevinO You can set breakpoint and do logging in a static initializer too, so that's no argument for anything.

Comment: @Makoto it's a general question (if such questions are acceptable!) and the code I provided is a random example I remembered.

Comment: @Mahozad: It becomes a bit too broad if you make it *too* general.  Narrow it down and make it easier for us to tackle.

Comment: My question is broad because static initializers seem ugly to me

Comment: @Mahozad then don't use them if you find them ugly.

Comment: @Lino Well what is the alternative way?!

Comment: @Mahozad look at the answer from Mureinik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a static list you will need to initialize it **somewhere*. A static initializer is a fair choice, although in this example, you can trim it down to a one liner:

```
private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("foo"));
```

Or, if this list shouldn't be modified during the program's lifetime, ever shorter:

```
private static final List<String> list = Collections.singletonList("foo");
```

Or as noted in the comment, in Java 9 and above:

```
private static final List<String> list = List.of("foo");
```

Comment: Starting with Java 9 you can aswell use `List.of("foo")` which creates an immutable list

Comment: Or `... list = List.of("foo");`